# Is there a way to ignore a compile time error for an incomplete function?

Tags: rust

I have some function

```
impl<const N: usize> SomeType<N> {
    fn some_func(&self, some_arg: &Pose3d64) -> &SomeType<N> {
        // pass
    }
}
```

And I want to land this code so that my colleagues can build on top of it, as such, the inside of these methods will not be implemented. When I do this I get compile time errors such as `error[E0308]: mismatched types`. Is there a way to just ignore these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [`todo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.todo.html) macro that will help.

or perhaps [`unimplemented`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unimplemented.html) would be more accurate for your purpose?

```rust
impl<const N: usize> SomeType<N> {
    fn some_func(&self, some_arg: &Pose3d64) -> &SomeType<N> {
        todo!()
        // or
        // unimplemented!()
        // or either with a message
        // todo!("don't forget to implement some_func on SomeType")
        // unimplemented!("SomeType cannot some_func")
    }
}
```

Both macros expand to a panic. Since panics are known to never return, Rust knows that you'll never return the wrong type out of such a function, silencing the compiler errors at the cost of runtime safety.

Comment: Can you explain how it works?